# Multicolumn List Box not showing the data I want it to?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing an Excel macro that matches names between two sheets and displays them in a list box. It has no problem in just matching names, but as soon as I try to include other data from one of the sheets, it doesn't seem to loop any more.

Here's my code:

```
Set matchedartistcell = Worksheets("Lots").Cells(curcell.Row, columnofregion)
matching_artist = matchedartistcell.Value
For i = 1 To maxmaster
    If Trim(Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(matching_artist) Then
       ListBox1.AddItem (Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 2))
       ListBox1.List(0, 1) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 4)
       ListBox1.List(0, 2) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 5)
       ListBox1.List(0, 3) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 6)
       End If
Next i
```

So basically, the first column shows a list of names... But the second, third and fourth column show data for the last match on the same row as the first match (if that makes sense?)

I feel like it's not looping in the way I would like it to, but I can't for the life of me figure out why... Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

EDIT for clarity:

I'm including some pictures to better describe the problem, using a test workbook

This is an example of the artists on the worksheet 'Master'
[image]

And this is an example of the worksheet I'm running the macro on ('Lots')
[image]

When I run the macro for the artwork by Hannah Smith, I expect the List Box to look something like

Mark Smith      British       1940     1999
Adam Smith      Australian    1901     1980
Hannah Smith    Canadian      1982

However, it returns this
[image]

Mark Smith is being given the nationality and dates of Hannah Smith, and neither Adam Smith or Hannah Smith have any extra info.

Comment: What gives you this "feeling" that it does not do as you expect it to? Did you try to debug the code? Maybe if you include a few break-points and check the values of the variables? You could also include a few message boxes or a `Debug.Print i & " : comparing " & Trim(Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 1)) & " to " & Trim(matching_artist)` and review the output thereof to ensure that things are going the way you expect / want them to go.

Comment: Hiya! I've edited my post to explain more about the issue, and why I have that feeling. The problem is the code runs fine, so I'm not being shown where the issue is. I will try what you've said now, thanks very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are always updating (in your code) the very first row of your ListBox. While `i` goes from 1 to the last row in that sheet, you are always updating `ListBox1.List(0, someColumn)`. So, you are always updating row 0 (which is the first row in the ListBox.

Give this a try and let me know if it works:

```
Set matchedartistcell = Worksheets("Lots").Cells(curcell.Row, columnofregion)
matching_artist = matchedartistcell.Value2
For i = 1 To maxmaster
    If Trim(Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 1)) = Trim(matching_artist) Then
       ListBox1.AddItem (Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 2))
       ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 4)
       ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 5)
       ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 6)
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense... I whacked it in and it works perfectly! You are such a star, thank you so much!